# C++ Compile time specification of array size

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

I'm attempting to create a struct to hold a file header within the declaration section of a class in a header file.  This involves calculation of a value that is known at compile time, and I want to use it to size an array within the header.

This is an extract from a header file of what I've most recently been trying:

```
const   uint    hFreeSiz    =   (1024 - sizeof(uint32_t) - sizeof (uint16_t)- sizeof (uint16_t) - sizeof(RId))/sizeof (RId);
template <const uint freedSiz>
struct  FBHead
{
    /** A magic number for the file.  Indicates both class and version. */
    uint32_t    fSig;
    /** The number of data bytes within each block. */
    uint16_t            blkSize;
    /** The number of records available for reuse.  */
    uint16_t            freedCnt;
    /** The id number of the last record written to the file.   */
    RId lstRec;
    RId freedRecs[freedSiz];
};
FBHead<hFreeSiz>    fbHead;
```

but it tells me:

> error:  invalid use of non-static data member 'FBFile::hFreeSiz'

I could calculate this by hand, but I'm trying to understand what's going on here and
why this isn't working.  Can anyone explain?  (I'm guessing that if I moved the
constant declaration outside the class, then it would work, but I'd really rather
keep it close to the stuff that it's used to modify.  In fact, if that's the only
answer, then I'll probably calculate
it by hand and put in comments about why that
particular number.)

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: With very small modifications (include cstdint, make RId an empty class) it compiles with VC++. In addition and in particular, no member FBFile::hFreeSiz exists in your code, so the error was not generated by the code you present. Share the code you are trying to find help for, please, not something invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way would be to use a `constexpr`, to tell the compiler it is an actual compile-time constant. See a simpler example:

```
constexpr int Size = sizeof(long) * 7;

class Foo
{
    int t[Size];
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
    static constexpr int Size = sizeof(long) * 7;
    int t[Size];
};
```

Comment: I notice that you moved the constant declaration outside the body of the class, which I hypothesized would work.  But I really want to keep the declaration close to the code that it modifies. <br>FWIW, if I change it to a constexpr I get the error "non-static data member 'hFreeSiz' declared 'constexpr'.  (Actually I had started out trying to use a constexpr, but this wasn't clear from my post.)

Comment: if you put the `constexpr` in class scope, you need to make it `static`. Otherwise, you're telling the compiler the value can vary per-object, which is not compile-time.